# How to use groupby and select to solve this problem

Tags: c#, json, linq

Given that i have 3 classed like below

```
public class Item1DTO
{
    public int sId { get; set; }
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }

}

public class Item1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class Item1VM
{
    public int sId { get; set; }
    public int groupId { get; set; }

    public List<Item1> items { get; set; }

}
```

And sample data

```
List<Item1DTO> data = new List<Item1DTO>();
data.Add(new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 1, name = "item1", year = "2019" });
data.Add(new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 1, name = "item1", year = "2020" });
data.Add(new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 2, name = "item1", year = "2020" });
data.Add(new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 2, name = "item1", year = "2020" });
data.Add(new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 3, name = "item1", year = "2020" });
```

I want to group this data by groupId and result will be a List of Item1VM class
so it can converted to this json data

```
[
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupId": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": 2019
            },
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": 2020
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupId": 2,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": 2020
            },
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": 2020
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupId": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": 2020
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Have tried my combination but im kinda new so the result is not as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you also post what you've tried as part of your question. However, the following Linq statement with a `GroupBy` will achieve what you want, notice the use of anonymous classes:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Item1DTO> data = 
        new List<Item1DTO>()
        {
            new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 1, name = "item1", year = "2019" },
            new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 1, name = "item1", year = "2020" },
            new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 2, name = "item1", year = "2020" },
            new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 2, name = "item1", year = "2020" },
            new Item1DTO { sId = 1, groupId = 3, name = "item1", year = "2020" }
        };

    var result = data
        .GroupBy(x => new { sId = x.sId, GroupId = x.groupId })
        .Select(g => new { sid = g.Key.sId, groupid = g.Key.GroupId, items = g.Select(x => new {x.name, x.year})});     
    
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
    
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

public class Item1DTO
{
    public int sId { get; set; }
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class Item1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class Item1VM
{
    public int sId { get; set; }
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public List<Item1> items { get; set; }
}
```

This returns the following data:

```
[
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupid": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": "2019"
            },
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": "2020"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupid": 2,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": "2020"
            },
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": "2020"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "groupid": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "year": "2020"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. And I also found one :).

Answer (score 0):

I found out my solution is as below

```
List<Item1VM> groupedCustomerList = data.GroupBy(item => new { item.sId, item.groupId })
.Select(g => new Item1VM
{
sId = g.Key.sId,
groupId = g.Key.groupId,
items = g.ToList().ConvertAll(x => new Item1
{
    name = x.name,
    year = x.year
})
})
.ToList();
```